# Registrator not listening to docker events

Tags: docker, consul

Consul is running fine

Registrator is running fine, but it's not listening to docker events.

ran registrator as :

docker run -d -h 10.153.6.131 -v /var/run/docker.sock:/tmp/docker.sock progrium/registrator consul://10.153.6.131:8500

also  tried

docker run -d -h 10.153.6.131 -P -v /var/run/docker.sock:/tmp/docker.sock progrium/registrator consul://10.153.6.131:8500

docker logs 73acf7b7f687b6c02e35ccfa6e2a41e42eea18a27292befd87d65fc665d20320
2014/10/07 21:39:49 registrator: Using consul registry backend at consul://10.153.6.131:8500

But not "Listening to docker events"

help please.

Answer (score 0):

I had a somewhat similar issue with etcd. Before listening for new events, registrator tries registering the services which are  already running. I don't know much about consul  (and did not know much about etcd either) but looking at the http communication give me the hint what was going wrong. Try

```
tcpdump -i any -A -s 0 host 10.153.6.131
```

Assuming you see traffic, watch closely to the response of consul. I would expect it to respond  with HTTP error codes which may point you to the root cause. If you don't see traffic, double check addresses and iptable configuration.

Comment: Thank you Steffan. It worked when i did: iptables -P OUTPUT ACCEPT and iptables -P INPUT ACCEPT